# Editing Json in Go without Unmarshalling into Structs First

Tags: json, go

I am having a bit of an issue. So I am writing a tool in go that works with some json files. 
The way the tool works is the devops member who is using it is supposed to upload their json file into the specified folder within the project and then that json file is used from there to deploy an api in api-gateway (the json is actually a swagger with extensions but that isn't particularly important to my question)

The issue I am having is I need to update ONE line in the json. Each file passed in will be different, but it is guaranteed to have a url in the same spot every time, just due to the nature of the project. I need to update this url in an automated fashion.

Due to the fact the json files are different, setting up hard coded structs and unmarshalling in order to edit is out of the question. The objective is for the devops members to not even have to go into the code, but rather just to deploy their files, which is the reason I was hoping for this to be automated.

So far my research has yielded nothing. It appears that Go only supports editing json if it is first unmarshaled into structs (see [Modifying JSON file using Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43713952/modifying-json-file-using-golang)). Is there a way to edit without the structs if i know for a fact what I am looking for will always be available within the json, despite each file being different?

This is only my first month using go, so there may be a simple solution. I have seen some mention of scanners from the megajson library, but I cannot seem to get that to work either

```
{
"paths": {
    "/account": {
        "post": {
            "something": "body",
            "api": {
                "uri": "http://thisiswhereineedtoedit.com"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "in the same spot"?  Do you mean at the same byte offset, or something else?  An example input and output might help explain the problem. Also, the JSON package can unmarshal JSON objects to maps.  Structs are not required.

Comment: @ThunderCat my apologize, poor phrasing on my part.  I meant in the json there will always be the same array and within that array there will always be a name "url" and I need to change the value of that. I will see if I can find an appropriate example to upload to make the question more clear.

Comment: @ThunderCat I have added a brief code snippet to show what it is I am attempting to do. The url portion is what I am attempting to change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unmarshal to `interface{}`.  Walk down nested objects to find the object with the value to set.  Set the value. Marshal back to JSON.

```
var root interface{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(d, &root); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// Walk down path to target object.
v := root
var path = []string{"paths", "/account", "post", "api"}
for i, k := range path {
    m, ok := v.(map[string]interface{})
    if !ok {
        log.Fatalf("map not found at %s", strings.Join(path[:i+1], ", "))
    }
    v, ok = m[k]
    if !ok {
        log.Fatalf("value not found at %s", strings.Join(path[:i+1], ", "))
    }
}

// Set value in the target object.
m, ok := v.(map[string]interface{})
if !ok {
    log.Fatalf("map not found at %s", strings.Join(path, ", "))
}
m["uri"] = "the new URI"

// Marshal back to JSON. Variable d is []byte with the JSON
d, err := json.Marshal(root)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Replace calls to log.Fatal with whatever error handling is appropriate for your application.

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/OL_UJVrrnTZ)

Comment: The OP might also look at things like <https://github.com/bcicen/jstream>. Another approach is to use the stock [streaming decoder](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Token) and a simple state machine which remembers the names of the fields whose object values it descends into, and patches up the value of the "uri" field as it goes.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can solve this is by reading the file and changing it.

Lets say you have the file as you mentioned:

> example.json

```
{
    "paths": {
        "/account": {
            "post": {
                "something": "body",
                "api": {
                    "uri": "http://thisiswhereineedtoedit.com"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And we want to change the line with `"uri"` in it.
***You should be more specific then I was in this example, make a placeholder or something - to avoid changing the wrong line.***

You can use a small program that would look something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    file := "./example.json"
    url := "\"uri\": \"supreme-uri\""

    // Read the file
    input, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    // Split it into lines
    lines := strings.Split(string(input), "\n")

    // Find the line that contains our "placeholder" / "uri"
    for i, line := range lines {
        if strings.Contains(line, "\"uri\":") {
            // Replace the line
            lines[i] = "\"uri\": " + url
        }
    }

    // Join lines and write to file
    output := strings.Join(lines, "\n")
    err = ioutil.WriteFile(file, []byte(output), 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}
```

And after running the program our `example.json` file now looks like this:

```
{
    "paths": {
        "/account": {
            "post": {
                "something": "body",
                "api": {
"uri": "supreme-uri"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Hope you find this solution useful, Good luck! :]*

Comment: Although the solution works in this specific case, I want to add that it could have been written in a more generic way so the solution can be used in a more generic way. But the audience, reading it until here will surely be able to write that themselve. So for inspiration it is a good solution, and for this case also, but a more generic solution with recursive search would be more useful. So you deserve the plus point from me.

Comment: @BertVerhees yup, I would agree. I think ThunderCat's solution is better. I'll just leave mine here in case somebody finds it useful as well. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Mihailo I ended up going with this solution because it does not require remarshalling, as the first solution did. The formatting of the json file is very important, and I was running into the issue of when unmarshalling, editing and then marshalling back, I was loosing the exact structure I needed (because I was using just generic interface instead of a proper struct) Thus, soley editing the file, while not as effiecient, maintained the exact structure I needed! Thanks!

Comment: Oh nice! Glad I could be of help. ThunderCat's method is great.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [filepath pkg from cross-plane runtime](https://github.com/crossplane/crossplane-runtime/blob/ba9d8c29a78cc4301985fdfcfdc43d46f063456f/pkg/fieldpath/paved_test.go#L592). You specify the JSON path and get or set the result you want like the example in the above link.